# Scroll UIPageViewController when contained scrollview is zoomed, like Apple's PhotoScroller example

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

In the apple PhotoScroller example, 3 zoomable images are displayed in a `UIPageViewController`.  You can zoom these images and page between them *even when* they are still zoomed.  My application uses the code from the PhotoScroller with the only difference being that my `UIPageViewController` is a child view controller of another `UIViewController` in my app - i.e. the paging functionality is contained within a view hierarchy.  In Apple's version, the `UIPageViewController` is the root view controller (set up by a storyboard actually).  In my code, I do not get the paging behavior unless I return the content to it's un-zoomed scale.  For my app I don't want to force the user to do this.  What do I need to do to get this working the way I want to?

**UPDATE**
I have determined that setting the page view controller as the root view controller manually causes the apple example code to exhibit the unwanted behavior.  that is, creating the page view controller in app delegate as

```
        // assign the first page to the pageViewController (our rootViewController)
    UIPageViewController *pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] init];
    pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    [pageViewController setViewControllers:@[pageZero]
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:NULL];
    self.window.rootViewController = pageViewController;
```

Causes a zoomed image to simply bounce at the edge, rather than zooming to the next image.  Original code is:

```
// assign the first page to the pageViewController (our rootViewController)
    UIPageViewController *pageViewController = (UIPageViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    [pageViewController setViewControllers:@[pageZero]
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:NULL];
```

Why does this break the behavior of scrolling while an image is zoomed ?

**SOLVED**

UIPageViewController must be initted properly, as

```
        _pageViewController =  [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
```

I had merely called `alloc] init]`.

Comment: Are you able to add some code or may be add a sample project to Github? Thanks.

Comment: let me see what i can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIPageViewController` must be initiated properly, as

```
        _pageViewController =  [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
```

I had merely called `alloc] init]` as a replacement for `storyboard`, which is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In order to page through your `UIPageViewController`even when zoomed into your images, I suggest creating separate zoomable `UIScrollview`s to contain each individual image then adding them as subviews to each page of the paging (and non-zoomable) `UIScrollview`; this way, by separating the gesture receivers, you can stay zoomed into the image while paging.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing, and exactly what the PhotoScroller example does, yet I don't get the behavior I would like.  Thanks for writing back though, I will update shortly with a github project containing example code so we can hash this out.

Comment: @deepwinter OK, I see. When you pan on the image, do you also want the image to pan? Or you do you just want the page to move to the next? I'm asking because it seems as if your inner UIScrollview's inherent UIPanGestureRecognizer is catching the pan intended for your outer UIScrollview... There are ways to work around this depending on what you're going for.